# Shell Scripting - Hour and Minute Computation

Tags: linux, shell

I am working on a shell script computation program wherein I want a script that computes for the total number of hours and minutes a particular user has been logged on to the system.  The script accepts one parameter, the login name.  Information like the complete name of the user, the current month and the dates the user logged on earliest during the month and the latest during the month. In the pseudo, I wanted somewhat like this:

```
[prompt]$   <your familyname>user_login  mycroft<enter>


For the Month of June :
         User :   mycroft
In Real life :   Mycroft Holmes
      period :    Mon Jun 16 to Sat Jun 28
total login time :   2 hours and 2 minutes
```

Is there a possible way to do this in Shell? I have been on blanks and errors until now.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `who` or `finger` program. Probably it's all you need.

Comment: is there a site where I can see a resource or a reference of it? turns out google gives random things.